# Shortcut to filter all elements, including self?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a shorter way to write this?

```
$myelements.find('*').andSelf().filter(myselector)
```

As far as I can tell, there's no way to search all descendants, including itself, without doing this?

If there's no function for this, I'll write one, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it already exists.

---

Here it is (*revised*):

```
(function($,undefined) {
    $.fn.all = function(selector) {
        if(selector===undefined) return this.find('*').andSelf();
        return this.find(selector).add(this.filter(selector));
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Nope, that wheel currently doesn't exist (there is no "anti"-`closest()` method that walks down the element hierarchy). You can go ahead and invent it. However, keep in mind that `andSelf()` *does* exist and its invocation only takes 9 characters.

Comment: @Frederic: It's not just 9 characters, because I need that stupid `.find('*')` in there too, which is probably inefficient because it's fetching every element, rather than just the ones I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't a way to do it in the API, though I think you may get better performance results if you do a normal `.find()` with a selector, then apply the `.filter()` only to the element itself.

```
var all = $myelements.find(myselector).add( $myelements.filter(myselector) );
```

This way, `querySelectorAll` can be used if you're using a valid selector.

Otherwise, you're doing the filter entirely with JavaScript code instead of native code (in supported browsers).

Of course you can make it into a plugin as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not really much better:

```
$($myelements + ', ' + $myelements + ' > *').filter(myselector);
```

Comment: Yeah, it's actually *more* characters. :D

Comment: Are you assuming `$myelements` is a string? The preceding `$` is a convention used to indicate it's a jquery object, which is evident by the fact I was using it like an object. i.e., this won't even work.

Comment: Fortran's not really much better than Java in that case :)